# Sphinx references to other sections containing section number and section title

Tags: latex, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I am using Sphinx to write a document with lots of references:

```
.. _human-factor:

The Human Factor
================

...

(see :ref:`human-factor` for details)
```

The compiled document contains something like this:

(see *The Human Factor* for details)

Instead I would like to have it formatted like this:

(see *5.1 The Human Factor* for details)

I tried to google the solution and I found out that the latex hyperref package can do this but I have no idea how to add this to the Sphinx build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved it by basically using numsec.py from here: https://github.com/jterrace/sphinxtr

I had to replace the doctree_resolved function with this one to get section number + title (e.g. "5.1 The Human Factor").

```
def doctree_resolved(app, doctree, docname):
    secnums = app.builder.env.toc_secnumbers
    for node in doctree.traverse(nodes.reference):
        if 'refdocname' in node:
            refdocname = node['refdocname']
            if refdocname in secnums:
                secnum = secnums[refdocname]
                emphnode = node.children[0]
                textnode = emphnode.children[0]

                toclist = app.builder.env.tocs[refdocname]
                anchorname = None
                for refnode in toclist.traverse(nodes.reference):
                    if refnode.astext() == textnode.astext():
                        anchorname = refnode['anchorname']
                if anchorname is None:
                    continue
                linktext = '.'.join(map(str, secnum[anchorname]))
                node.replace(emphnode, nodes.Text(linktext
                    + ' ' + textnode))
```

To make it work one needs to include the numsec extension in conf.py and also to add :numbered: in the toctree like so:

```
.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 1
   :numbered:
```

Comment: I found out that this solution only works for documents that do not use parts. The internal section numbering exposed in secnums is restarted with every part :-(